# Slickgrid, change row color on hover

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid grid that I want to change the rows background color on rows hover. I tried this:

```
$(".slick-row").mouseenter(function(){ 
    $(this).css("background-color","red"); 
}).mouseleave(function(){ 
    $(this).css("background-color","white"); 
});
```

but it's not working. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using slickgrid the target rows will be dynamic so use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handlers.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".slick-row", function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}).on('mouseleave', ".slick-row", function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Also change the selector `$(document)` to a more specific one.

Comment: sounds like working but only odd rows has the background when hovering them the even row no.

Comment: looks like some css from your end is overwriting the style.. do you have a different style for the odd rows

Comment: @OussamaLord I just tested it in the slickgrid example page http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html and it seems fine - go to the page -> open browser console -> copy & paste the script and execute it -> hover over the rows

Comment: Noticed that too, I'm checking, can you point me to the odd row style please?

Comment: @OussamaLord without seeing your page or more information about your page can't do much

Comment: Thanks, fixed. It was a conflict between the slickgrid css files and the "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" file, I had to remove that file.

Answer (score 10):

Why not just add CSS?

```
.slick-row:hover{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
}
```

Comment: WOW Excellent
Only add this css Your Job is Done
Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think of using event delegation, but I solved it this way and it work properly even with slick grid re-rendering.

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#newgrid", data, columns, options);

 grid.onMouseEnter.subscribe(function(e, args) {
     $(".slick-cell").hover(function() {
         $(this.parentNode.children).removeClass('slick-cell-hovered');
     });
 });

 grid.onMouseLeave.subscribe(function(e, args) {
     $(".slick-cell").hover(function() {
         $(this.parentNode.children).addClass('slick-cell-hovered');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BAm45/)

```
$(".slick-row").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).css("background-color","red"); 
}).mouseout(function(){ 
    $(this).css("background-color","white"); 
});
```

Comment: -1 because hover is supposed to abstract away from mousein/out which it encapsulates and are also deprecated in favor of mouseenter/leave nowa-days.